# Output from convolving two functions with Dirac delta functions

Tags: convolution

I have two functions in a convolution problem, and I'm struggling to wrap my head conceptually around what I'm supposed to do. The functions are:
\begin{align*}
h(t) &= \delta(t-1) + \delta(t-3)\\
x(t) &= \delta(t-3) - 2\delta(t-4),
\end{align*}

and I want to find $y(t) = x(t)*h(t).$

Comment: Does $x*h$ mean pointwise multiplication, or does it actually mean _convolution_? Attempted pointwise multiplication is a problem, but convolution would be a standard thing.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is convolution. I know how to calculate y(t) if h(t) contained a unit function but both functions containing Dirac deltas is confusing me.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll change your title to reflect that. Otherwise people may be confused...

Comment: Sure, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convolution is defined as
\begin{align*}
x(t) * h(t)
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)\,h(t-\tau)\,d\tau\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[\delta(\tau-3) - 2\delta(\tau-4)]\,[\delta(t-\tau-1) + \delta(t-\tau-3)]\,d\tau\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\tau-3)\,\delta(t-\tau-1)\,d\tau\\
&+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\tau-3)\,\delta(t-\tau-3)\,d\tau\\
&-2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\tau-4)\,\delta(t-\tau-1)\,d\tau\\
&-2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\tau-4)\,\delta(t-\tau-3)\,d\tau.
\end{align*}
Now the way the Dirac delta function works, it "picks out" values under the integral sign. The fact that the other function is a Dirac delta function doesn't change this. So we obtain:
\begin{align*}
x(t) * h(t)
&=\delta(t-3-1)+\delta(t-3-3)-2\delta(t-4-1)-2\delta(t-7-3)\\
&=\delta(t-4)+\delta(t-6)-2\delta(t-5)-2\delta(t-10).
\end{align*}

Comment: Actually, the fact that the other function is a $\delta$ does change the nature of the game considerably. It matters a lot that it's a convolution, as opposed to just an integral.

Comment: @paulgarrett: I suppose if you had $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-a)\,\delta(t-a)\,dt,$ then it would matter. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, a purported pointwise square of $\delta$s is a problem, and some mildly serious care is required to see how "convolution" evidently side-steps this.

Comment: Ha! That's a great phrase: "mildly serious care". I'll have to remember that one!

Answer (score 0):

The spirit of the thing is that $\delta*f=f$ for almost any $f$. Similarly, letting $T_af(x)=f(x+a)$ be the translation operator, $(T_a\delta)*f=T_af$.

It *does* require something (there are several choices) to believe/prove/know that $\delta*\delta=\delta$... but, granting this, $(T_a\delta)*(T_b\delta)=T_{a+b}\delta$.